# Scaling for TYPO3 site

Tags: php, apache, content-management-system, typo3, infrastructure

I'm asked by a customer to deliver a TYPO3 based website with the following parameters:

- small amount of content (about 50 pages)
- very little change frequency
- average availability about 95%/day
- 20% of pages are restricted, only available after login
- No requirements for fancy typo3 extensions or something else (only Typo3 core)
- Medium sized pages
- Only limited digital assets (images etc.) included

I have the requirements to build an infrastructure to serve up to 1000 concurrent users. With the assumption of having an average think time of 30 sec. this would result in 33 Requests per second.

What would an infrastructure look like?

I know that system scaling is a highly individual task depending on the implementation of the system and needs testing, but I need a first indication where to start (single server, separating components to different servers,...).

Any idea?

Comment: It's too complex subject to give you a valuable answer. However, I'd first focus on optimizing performance of the TYPO3 website and if it wasn't enough, THEN I'd focus on the system side of the problem. So google for "TYPO3 performance". 3 keywords might help you focus on the right stuff: **eAccelerator**, **static file cache**, **memcached**.

Comment: Don't use eAccelerator, use xCache or APC instead. Static file cache is explained below. Don't use memcached as Caching backend, but APC or Redis (depenent on your PHP setup) instead.

Comment: @StephenKing: eaccelerator is a php cache and not a database cache. He should uses xCache or APC additionally and also memcached and Redis.

Comment: I know what eAccelerator is. It is not maintained anymore and easily causes trouble, if it is compiled with wrong options (and PHPdoc comments are stripped). So use (xCache||APC) as Byte-code cache plus (APC||redis) as Caching backend. Memcached as Caching Backend causes trouble, if you run out of space. See http://wiki.typo3.org/Caching_framework

Comment: This question was interesting in 2012, but I think now is regarded as too opinion-based (or needs focus). I will vote to close for now.

Answer (score 3):

Easier solution is [EXT:nc_staticfilecache](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/nc_staticfilecache/current/). This saves the static pages as HTML and your web server automatically delivers them through rewrite rules (in case of Apache through mod_rewrite). This works very well for static content and should already enable you to do >100req/s.

The even more fancier way is to use [Varnish Cache](http://www.varnish-cache.org). Varnish is a reverse proxy server that holds your web site content in memory and can run on a dedicated host. If you configure it correctly (send correct cache headers!), it serves you line speed (some million req/s). There is also a TYPO3 Extension [moc_varnish](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/moc_varnish/current/), which e.g. purges the varnish cache, when a page is changed in TYPO3. Also support for edge side includes exists to e.g. only retrieve the user-specific data from TYPO3 and use the static parts of a page from varnish cache (everything except the "*Welcome user Foo Bar*".. ;)).

As mentioned: Don't forget to configure correct cache headers (Expires etc) for your assets. This already removes some load from your web server.

Comment: BTW: Does your client really expect 1000 concurrent visitors, or does he only imagine that there could be that many? ;-)

Comment: No, I do not really think that it will be that much but this is the basis for the contract ;-)

Comment: The need to proxy is not yet proven, in my view - but good info, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible, already made something like this. You need at least one dedicated server with >= 8GB of RAM.

If we are speaking about infrastructure, the minimal combination is :

- nginx/Varnish for front/load balancing
- Apache HTTP Server
- MySQL could be on standalone server, could be clustered

Performance optimization is very important in such cases.

Some links for further reading :

- http://techblog.evo.pl/en/how-to-boost-speed-up-your-typo3-website-with-nginx/
- http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/nginx-varnish-apache-magento-typo3.html
- http://wiki.typo3.org/Performance_tuning

Comment: Why not nginx or lighttpd? Apache is complicated and a beast. And why a dedicated server? A kms is much more affordable?

Comment: Apache is some heavy, yes, but it has very good functional basis thanks and could be tuned to avoid overloads. nginx could be used, yes. What is it "kms", sorry ?

Comment: It's a typo. I mean KVM, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine. You can have more control over the guest. You can change for example kernel parameters and compile kernel.

Comment: If You need such personalization of the kernel, why not. But using virtualization could add some performance overheads.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put this on a single dedicated server (or well specified VPS) but maybe keep all the static assets on a third party CDN so you can focus on the dynamic stuff. I don't know Typo3 but can't see any reason why you couldn't have your db on the same server for this level of usage - there is sure to be caching options of various kinds. Or perhaps consider a cloud server, so if you need more oomph, just add more resources.

Edit: I don't think it is a good idea to build a scalable architecture just yet e.g. proxy servers and all that stuff. If it is slow and you find you really can't cope with one machine, scale up at that point. I'm of the view you can make do with a much simpler architecture given your expected traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a virtual sserver or a ksm and a good mysql and php configuration. When I have a ksm I would tweak Linux and use iptables for traffic shaping. A dedicated root server would be nice but it's expensive. Then I would think about using a nginx or lighttpd webserver with eaccellerator and memcache. If that doesn't help I would try to compile php and mysql with optimize flags or I would try to compile it with the Intel C Compiler. ICC can optimize C code better then gcc. If the server has many ram I would use ramdisk.

Comment: Sorry, bad answer IMHO. Don't try to tweek the operating system. Start with a good setup of the application (TYPO3 + PHP) itself.

Comment: @StephenKing: You should learn to read. I don't have the means to tweak the system but it's common pratise in Linux so why not if you have the means?

Comment: He's asking for a solution for a web application. Why do you expect him to compile server software? Maybe he's using a managed server, shared hosting, or has a system administrator, who might do this. He can ruin all performance because of a bad TYPO3 configuration, but he cannot fix this by optimized binaries or a ramdisk.

Comment: @StephenKing: I've fixed my answer and deleted the proxy thing.